# How to extract bits from an integer in C?

Tags: c, binary, bit, bit-shift

So i'm trying to extracts bits from a 32=bit binary integer using bit shifting and masking, but i'm sightly off by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

  int number = 87; //0000 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 0111
  int i;
  int bit;
  int g = 0;

   for(i = 32; i > 0; i--){

   if(g%4==0 && g!=0){
     printf(" ");
   }
    g++;
    bit = (number >> i) & 1;
    printf("%d", bit);
  }

  printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger?

Comment: Also, remember that bit numbers are zero-based. The first bit is number `0`, the last bit in a 32-bit number is number `31`.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: ahhh, nevermind.  Stupid for loop was throwing me off.  Thanks for the hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is logic missing in your code..

Use

```
for(i **= 31**; i **>=** 0; i--)
```

instead of

```
for(i **= 32**; i **>** 0; i--)
```

Comment if it works for you